# How can I change manifest file in Java

Tags: java, jar

How i can change class-path in mainfest file.

I have external jar file in folder:

```
Class-Path: folder/AbsoluteLayout.jar
```

I want to add my external jar file to my **JAR MyProject.jar** and change mainfast..
What should I write in mainfestu to link against the library into my jar..

```
Class-Path: path to my externalJar in MyProject.jar
```

[image]

I hope you understand, thank you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do :

```
jar cfm jar-file manifest-addition input-file(s)
```

- The `c` option indicates that you want to create a JAR file.
- The `m` option indicates that you want to merge information from an existing file into the manifest file of the JAR file you're creating.
- The `f` option indicates that you want the output to go to a file (the JAR file you're creating) rather than to standard output.
- `manifest-addition` is the name (or path and name) of the existing text file whose contents you want to add to the contents of JAR file's manifest.

More info:

- [Modifying a Manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Is there an approach that does not create an a new jar but simply updates the existing one?

Answer (score 3):

1. Extract the manifest:

   jar xvf MyProject.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2. Edit the manifest
3. Reinsert the edited manifest:

   jar uvf MyProject.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

If you encounter the manifest issue mentioned below by Pabasara, then try this approach

```
unzip -o MyProject.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
sed -i "s/.*LOOK_FOR.*/REPLACE_WITH/" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
zip MyProject.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: In 3) it should be `uvfm`. Otherwise  the existing MANIFEST.MF file will be removed not replaced.